# Regex capture group ( ) within character set [ ]

Tags: regex

I would like to match space characters () only if they are followed by a hash (`#`).

This is what `( #)` below is trying to do, which is a capture group. (I tried escaping the brackets, otherwise the brackets are not recognised properly within a group set). However, this is not working.

The below regex

```
/#[a-zA-Z\( #\)]+/g
```

matches all of the below

```
#CincoDeMayo #Derby party with UNLIMITED #seafood towers
```

while I would like to match `#CincoDeMayo #Derby` and separately `#seafood`

Is there any way to specify captures groups `()` within a character set `[]`?

Comment: To match space characters only when followed by a hash: `\s(?=#)`. To match words after a hash in your sample text: `#\w+`. To combine these two requirements: `\s*(?=#)#\w+`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Character classes are meant to match a single character, thus, it is not possible to define a *character sequence* inside a character class.

I think you want to match specific consecutive hashtags. Use

```
/#[a-zA-Z]+(?: +#[a-zA-Z]+)*/g
```

or

```
/#[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+#[a-zA-Z]+)*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI7Bjf/2).

**Details**

- `#[a-zA-Z]+` - a `#` followed with 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group...

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `#[a-zA-Z]+` - a `#` followed with 1+ ASCII letters
- `)*` - ... that repeats 0 or more times.